# Exporting layers to a new file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, export

I am updating construction works using QGIS. Every 6 weeks I update the map with new changes, but need to save each survey cycle as a new file. I have a map set up already with all the layers etc.

My issue is that I'm about to start a new survey cycle and need to save the changes I find. I have saved the project for August into a new file, but how do I export all the existing layers etc into a new folder so that when I make changes, it will be for new layer files instead of updating the layer files for the previous batches project?

Comment: Having read, and re-read, your question several times, it sounds as if you are possibly confusing a QGIS project file (.qgs) from the separate layers in you project which contain the data (probably Shapefiles?). What layers contain the data you want to make changes to, are they shapefiles? Is there more than one layer that is changing or more?

Comment: Ah OK. Yes i basically want to make new shapefiles for each new set of surveys I do and saving them in a new folder for each month. As far as i was aware though I would also need to make a new project file each time though also, is this not the case? Can I simply creat new shapefiles for each month and save these into a folder?

Comment: How have you worked this out in the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess your are looking for the plugin [QConsolidate](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qconsolidate/) in the official repository which enables you to make a copy of nearly all layers (at least rasterdata and shapefiles) and the project to a new directory.

It's useful to pack your data onto an usbdrive for convient datatransfer or archiving.
Be aware that images/pictures/other resources only used in the composer won't be copied to the new directory

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Qgis 3.12 here.

[This is](https://www.cadlinecommunity.co.uk/hc/en-us/articles/360000923638-QGIS-Creating-GeoPackage-Layers) an easy alternative, exporting the layers of your project to a single geopackage.

- Open the toolbox pane: Processing menu > Toolbox
- then: Database > Package layers

A dialog opens. In *input layers* you choose all the layers you want to export together, then choose a filename for your Geopackage and execute. Now you have an independent file, a database itself, with all the selected layers.

For your next project iteration you just can copy this file into a new different one and import the new geopackage file into Qgis.

Hope it helps.

Note: I don't have anything to do with the Cadlinecomunity website but [its post](https://www.cadlinecommunity.co.uk/hc/en-us/articles/360000923638-QGIS-Creating-GeoPackage-Layers) is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Having just read your latest comment...

A QGIS project file only 'points' to where your data is. It is not the data itself.

To answer your question, whenever you need to take a snapshot of the data in a shapefile, simply right-click on the layer in your layer list and 'Save As'.

[image]

You can then browse to where you want to save the file and give it a name.

If you just want to save it as a snapshot and not add it as a new layer into your QGIS project then deselect the `Add saved file to map`.

You also have options for saving only selected features, if you just wanted to make a snapshot of just a selection